# Regexp for special string

Tags: regex, shell

I need a regexp which matches to the sting which

- starts with $
- ends with $
- contains some alphabetical characters (not defined how many)

e.g.

```
$ABC$    # ok
$ABCDEF$ # ok
$ABC     # not ok
AC$      # not ok
```

Comment: If you read the tag wiki for regex you will see you are supposed to tell us where you are trying to use this regex. PHP and .net have different supported syntax, and the / / notation isn't used everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\$[A-Za-z]*\$$
```

This will match 0 or more characters in between dollar signs. If you want to match one or more, use `^\$[A-Za-z]+\$$`.

This could probably be written with fewer characters, but I have no indication of what regex engine you're using, so I can't use any specific features.

Answer (score 2):

This is the regex you want:

```
/^\$[a-z]+\$$/i
```

Components explained:

1. `^` - Start matches only from the beginning of the input
2. `\$` - Match a literal `$` (the `\` is used for escaping special chars)
3. `[a-z]` - Match any of the letters (combined with the `i` modifier at the end matches both lowercase and uppercase)
4. `+` - match items from the preceding character class 1 or more times
5. `\$` - See 2
6. `$` - End matches only at the end of the input
7. `/` - Is the standard delimited for regex, but it may vary in some languages
8. `i` - Placed at the end is the Case Insensitive modifier

Good reading: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
^\$[a-zA-Z]+\$$
```

should work. Syntax depends on where do you use it